# Passing object parameter to hub method

Tags: c#, .net, signalr

Although there are many questions like that on the web, I haven't found a right one that solves my issue:

I have a SignalR hub method:

```
public ClientResponses ProcessRequest(ClientRequest request) {...}
```

This method gets `ClientRequest` object as parameter:

```
[Serializable]
public class ClientRequest : BaseClientRequest
{
    [JsonProperty("input")]
    public string Input { get; set; }
}
```

I call this method from the client like that:

```
var input = new Input(message);
var jsonInput = JSON.stringify(input);
hubProxy.server.processRequest(jsonInput);
```

When sending, their values are:

[image]

But the method at the server side (`ProcessRequest`) never called.

When I change this method to get a string type parameter and sent a pure string from the client it works properly.

Comment: I don't think you have to JSON.stringify()

Comment: @Steve Yes you right, it works now. Thank you !

Comment: @Steve Maybe do you know what should I do with this question? Delete it? Or if you'd like you answer it. Thank you

Comment: Although it was a trivial answer, I have answered as someone in future might have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that the line :

```
var jsonInput = JSON.stringify(input);
```

isn't needed as you can send straight javascript objects to SignalR.